# Rotating a needle from 0 to 140 android

Tags: android

I'm designing a new rpm gauge. I have a problem with the rotating needle, I want to make the needle go from o to 1400 after press of a button. I tried but i could get only to last value  but not the intermediate value. How to make it work?

```
package com.Jay.race;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

public class Gag extends View {

private static final String TAG = "GMF";
public static float angle_of_deviation;
Gag speedo_obj;
private Handler handler;
// drawing tools
private RectF rimRect;
private Paint rimPaint;
private Paint rimCirclePaint;

private RectF faceRect;
private Bitmap faceTexture;
private Paint facePaint;
private Paint rimShadowPaint;

private Paint scalePaint;
private RectF scaleRect;

private Paint titlePaint;
private Path titlePath;

private Paint logoPaint;
private Bitmap logo;
private Matrix logoMatrix;
private float logoScale;

private Paint handPaint;
private Path handPath;
private Paint handScrewPaint;

private Paint backgroundPaint;
// end drawing tools

private Bitmap background; // holds the cached static part
// private Bitmap mFinalbitmap =
// BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back);

// Scale configuration: totalNotches, centerValue, minScaleValue,
// maxScaleValue and
// scaleTitle can be given as property.
// It's better to call this notch i.s.o. nick. There is a saying...
// "Turn it up a notch"
private int totalNotches = 100;
private int incrementPerLargeNotch = 10;
private int incrementPerSmallNotch = 2;
private float degreesPerNotch = 360.0f / totalNotches;
private int cas = 0;
private int scaleCenterValue = 90; // the one in the top center (12 o'clock)
private int scaleMinValue = 0;
private int scaleMaxValue = 140;

private int scaleColor = 0x9f004d0f;
// hand dynamics -- all are angular expressed in F degrees
private boolean handInitialized = true;
private float handPosition = scaleMinValue;
private float handTarget = scaleCenterValue;
private float handVelocity = 0.0f;
private float handAcceleration = 0.0f;
private long lastHandMoveTime = -1L;

public Gag(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    init(context, null);

}

public Gag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public Gag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    speedo_obj = this;

    handler = new Handler();
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    // Get the properties from the resource file.
    if (context != null && attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.Temperature);
        totalNotches = a.getInt(R.styleable.Temperature_totalNotches,
                totalNotches);
        incrementPerLargeNotch = a.getInt(
                R.styleable.Temperature_incrementPerLargeNotch,
                incrementPerLargeNotch);
        incrementPerSmallNotch = a.getInt(
                R.styleable.Temperature_incrementPerSmallNotch,
                incrementPerSmallNotch);
        scaleCenterValue = a.getInt(
                R.styleable.Temperature_scaleCenterValue, scaleCenterValue);
        scaleMinValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.Temperature_scaleMinValue,
                scaleMinValue);
        scaleMaxValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.Temperature_scaleMaxValue,
                scaleMaxValue);
        scaleColor = a.getInt(R.styleable.Temperature_scaleColor,
                scaleColor);
        String scaleUpperTitle = a
                .getString(R.styleable.Temperature_scaleUpperTitle);
        String scaleLowerTitle = a
                .getString(R.styleable.Temperature_scaleLowerTitle);

        // if (scaleUpperTitle != null) this.scaleUpperTitle =
        // scaleUpperTitle;
        // if (scaleLowerTitle != null) this.scaleLowerTitle =
        // scaleLowerTitle;

    }

    initdrawtools();
}

private void initdrawtools() {
    rimRect = new RectF(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.9f, 0.9f);

    // the linear gradient is a bit skewed for realism
    rimPaint = new Paint();
    rimPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    rimPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0.40f, 0.0f, 0.60f, 1.0f, Color
            .rgb(0xf0, 0xf5, 0xf0), Color.rgb(0x30, 0x31, 0x30),
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

    rimCirclePaint = new Paint();
    rimCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    rimCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    rimCirclePaint.setColor(Color.argb(0x4f, 0x33, 0x36, 0x33));
    rimCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(0.005f);

    float rimSize = 0.02f;
    faceRect = new RectF();
    faceRect.set(rimRect.left + rimSize, rimRect.top + rimSize,
            rimRect.right - rimSize, rimRect.bottom - rimSize);

    faceTexture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
            R.drawable.plastic);
    BitmapShader paperShader = new BitmapShader(faceTexture,
            Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
    Matrix paperMatrix = new Matrix();
    facePaint = new Paint();
    facePaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paperMatrix.setScale(1.0f / faceTexture.getWidth(),
            1.0f / faceTexture.getHeight());
    paperShader.setLocalMatrix(paperMatrix);
    facePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    facePaint.setShader(paperShader);

    rimShadowPaint = new Paint();
    rimShadowPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(0.5f, 0.5f, faceRect
            .width() / 2.0f,
            new int[] { 0x00000000, 0x00000500, 0x50000500 }, new float[] {
                    0.96f, 0.96f, 0.99f }, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    rimShadowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    scalePaint = new Paint();
    scalePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    scalePaint.setColor(scaleColor);
    scalePaint.setStrokeWidth(0.005f);
    scalePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    scalePaint.setTextSize(0.045f);
    scalePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
    scalePaint.setTextScaleX(0.8f);
    scalePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    // The scale rectangular is located .10 from the outer rim.
    float scalePosition = 0.10f;

    scaleRect = new RectF();
    scaleRect.set(faceRect.left + scalePosition, faceRect.top
            + scalePosition, faceRect.right - scalePosition,
            faceRect.bottom - scalePosition);

    // The title rectangular is located .25 from the outer rim.
    float titlePosition = 0.130f;

    // titleRect = new RectF();
    /*
     * titleRect.set(faceRect.left + titlePosition, faceRect.top +
     * titlePosition, faceRect.right - titlePosition, faceRect.bottom -
     * titlePosition);
     */

    titlePaint = new Paint();
    titlePaint.setColor(0xaf946109);
    titlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    titlePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    titlePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    titlePaint.setTextSize(0.05f);
    titlePaint.setTextScaleX(0.8f);

    // titlePath = new Path();
    // titlePath.addArc(new RectF(0.24f, 0.24f, 0.76f, 0.76f), -180.0f,
    // -180.0f);
    // Put the title in a rectangular and not as stated above. The code
    // above is
    // the original code and it is hard to maintain these values. Setting
    // the start
    // angle and sweep to a positive value causes the title to be displayed
    // in the
    // top half of the scale i.e.: titlePath.addArc(titleRect, 180.0f,
    // 180.0f);

    logoPaint = new Paint();
    logoPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
            R.drawable.logo);
    logoMatrix = new Matrix();
    logoScale = (1.0f / logo.getWidth()) * 0.3f;
    ;
    logoMatrix.setScale(logoScale, logoScale);

    handPaint = new Paint();
    handPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    handPaint.setColor(0xff392f2c);
    handPaint.setShadowLayer(0.01f, -0.005f, -0.005f, 0x7f000000);
    handPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    // This code draws the hand with the tip facing north. When the hand is
    // not rotated, it points to the center value.
    handPath = new Path();
    handPath.moveTo(0.5f, .5f + 0.05f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.030f, 0.5f + 0.1f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.002f, 0.5f - 0.32f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.002f, 0.5f - 0.32f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.030f, 0.5f + 0.1f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f, 0.5f + 0.05f);
    handPath.addCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.035f, Path.Direction.CW);

    handScrewPaint = new Paint();
    handScrewPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    handScrewPaint.setColor(0xff493f3c);
    handScrewPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Width spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec));
    Log.d(TAG, "Height spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec));

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
    int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

    int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);

    setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension);
}

private int chooseDimension(int mode, int size) {
    if (mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        return size;
    } else { // (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        return getPreferredSize();
    }
}

private int getPreferredSize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 300;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

    // canvas.drawBitmap(mFinalbitmap, 480, 690, null);

    drawBackground(canvas);

    float scale = (float) getWidth();
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);

    // drawLogo(canvas);
    drawHand(canvas);

    canvas.restore();

}

private void drawHand(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    canvas.drawPath(handPath, handPaint);
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.01f, handScrewPaint);

}

private float valueToAngle(float value) {
    float fix = 0;

    fix = (value - scaleCenterValue) / 2.0f * degreesPerNotch;
    Log.d(TAG, "FIXXXX" + fix);

    return fix;

}

private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (background == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Background not created");
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, backgroundPaint);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Size changed to " + w + "x" + h);

    regenerateBackground();
}

private void regenerateBackground() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // free the old bitmap
    if (background != null) {
        background.recycle();
    }

    background = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas backgroundCanvas = new Canvas(background);
    float scale = (float) getWidth();
    backgroundCanvas.scale(scale, scale);

    drawRim(backgroundCanvas);
    drawFace(backgroundCanvas);
    drawScale(backgroundCanvas);
}

private void drawScale(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    canvas.drawOval(scaleRect, scalePaint);

    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNotches; ++i) {
        float y1 = scaleRect.top;
        float y2 = y1 - 0.015f;
        float y3 = y1 - 0.025f;

        int value = notchToValue(i);

        if (i % (incrementPerLargeNotch / incrementPerSmallNotch) == 0) {
            if (value >= scaleMinValue && value <= scaleMaxValue) {
                // draw a nick
                canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y3, scalePaint);

                String valueString = Integer.toString(value);
                // Draw the text 0.15 away from y3 which is the long nick.
                canvas.drawText(valueString, 0.5f, y3 - 0.015f, scalePaint);
            }
        } else {
            if (value >= scaleMinValue && value <= scaleMaxValue) {
                // draw a nick
                canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y2, scalePaint);
            }
        }

        canvas.rotate(degreesPerNotch, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    }
    canvas.restore();
}

private int notchToValue(int value) {
    int rawValue = ((value < totalNotches / 2) ? value
            : (value - totalNotches)) * incrementPerSmallNotch;
    int shiftedValue = rawValue + scaleCenterValue;
    return shiftedValue;
}

private void drawFace(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawOval(faceRect, facePaint);
    // draw the inner rim circle
    canvas.drawOval(faceRect, rimCirclePaint);
    // draw the rim shadow inside the face
    canvas.drawOval(faceRect, rimShadowPaint);

}

private void drawRim(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // first, draw the metallic body
    canvas.drawOval(rimRect, rimPaint);
    // now the outer rim circle
    canvas.drawOval(rimRect, rimCirclePaint);
}

void moveHand(int tango) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
        handPosition = i;
        Log.d(TAG, "I" + i);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        invalidate();

    }
}

public void calculateAngleOfDeviation(int randomly_generated_value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
    RectF bounds = new RectF();
    handPath.computeBounds(bounds, true);

    mMatrix.postRotate(valueToAngle(50), 0.5f, 0.5f);

    handPath.transform(mMatrix);

    speedo_obj.invalidate();
}
```

}
`

Comment: you need to animate this -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html

Comment: i have posted my code. Please do check and let me know

Comment: You really should avoid sleeps in your UI thread (moveHand() for example). Instead create a Handler and post a runnable delayed.

Comment: If any examples wrt the problem. please do post it.